# FPDF show footer page number for specific pages with different format

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

In FPDF, if there are 4 pages to print then FPDF will calculate page as 0,1,2,3

For generating page number, It will skip the 0th page (`if($this->page>0){ }` in  `AddPage()` function) and calculate line number from next page onwards(1,2,3) and in `close()` function it just add another page number (4)
So total there will be 4 pages and in output it will show line number correctly.

Current scenario: I need to determine the page number format dynamically. So in  function `AddPage($orientation='')` I added another parameter called `$show_number`. So if show number is 1 then need to show the page number **for that page** in a specific way, else show in another way.

Problem: Because the FPDF skips the first page and adds the last page number in close() function I could not show the page number correctly.
For example, if I wanted to show the number in a different way on the third page, I'm getting the result in 2nd page instead.

Comment: Your text is very confusing. Show us some code and maybe to images, one how the pdf output currently looks like, and a mockup of how you'd like it to be.

Comment: please provide the code and the image of the pdf look like